# Scipy.spatial does not contain 'qhull'

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi, qhull

This is my first question on this site. Let's cut right to it:

I'm trying to create Voronoi diagrams with `scipy` in Python 3.8 on Kubuntu 20.04, however the problem seems to be that I cannot access the `Voronoi` class in `scipy.spatial` because it does not contain a reference to `qhull`. Other classes like ConvexHull which are also dependent on `qhull` are inaccessible as well. Trying to open `qhull` produces `Cannot find reference to qhull in __init__.py` in PyCharm, and I cannot navigate to it. Looking at the SciPy-Documentation, it would seem as though `qhull` is expected to be delivered alongside `scipy`, as there is no further information on how to install it.

So far I have tried:

1. Upgrading `scipy` to the latest version 1.5.3
2. Fresh install of `scipy` - I ran `pip install` with verbose, but no errors or warnings (which should be color-coded afaik) appeared
3. Installing `qhull-bin` via console
4. Building `qhull` manually

None of these approaches seems to have changed anything, except I can run `qhull` in the console now, but that's not really what I'm looking for.

I would appreciate any kind of advice you might have for me.

Comment: If I understand well, this statement `from scipy.spatial import Voronoi` fails? If yes, could you paste the full Traceback generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I should have tried to actually run my code. Turns out it was installed all along, just that PyCharm didn't, and still doesn't, have access to any `qhull` files or references, meaning the error within PyCharm hasn't disappeard, but the code works.